# OpenMp: Best way to create an array with size of the number of threads

Tags: c++, openmp

specific i have to calculate pi parallel with OpenMp. I am just allowed using #omp parallel. So i wanted to create an array with the size of the number of processes and then calculating partially the sum parallel and then calculating the sums together. But it's unfortunately impossible to get the number of threads before the parallel version. So is the best way to create a very large array and initializing it with 0.0 and then calculating everything together or is there a better way? I would appreciate every answer. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I believe you mean `omp_get_max_threads()` since `omp_get_num_threads()` returns `1` when called outside of a parallel region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, it is not impossible to obtain the number of threads in advance. The OpenMP runtime does not simply launch a random number of threads without any control from both the programmer and the program user. On the contrary, it follows a well-defined mechanism to determine that number, which is [described in detail in the OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu35.html#x55-880002.6.1). Specifically, unless you've supplied a higher fixed number of threads with the `num_threads`, the number of threads OpenMP launches is limited by the value of the special *internal control variable* (ICV for short) called *nthreads-var*. The way to set this ICV is via the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable or via the `omp_set_num_threads()` call (the latter method overrides the former). The value of *nthreads-var* is accessible by calling `omp_get_max_threads()`. For other ICVs see [the specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu32.html#x51-710002.5.3).

All you need to do is call `omp_get_max_threads()` and use the return value as the size of your array, for the number of threads will not exceed that value, given that you aren't calling `omp_set_num_threads()` with a larger value afterwards and aren't applying the `num_threads` clause to the `parallel` construct.