# How do I determine the default thread count OpenMP uses for a parallel section?

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a function that roughly looks like this:

```
void doParallelWork(std::vector<WorkItem> &workItems, unsigned int threadCount = 0) {
    // Use OpenMP default thread count if threadCount not set
    if(threadCount == 0) {
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            threadCount = omp_get_num_threads();
        };
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threadCount)
    for(int i = 0; i < workItems.size(); i++) {
        doWork(workItems.at(i));
    }
}
```

I'd like the function to use the OpenMP default thread count if threadCount is unspecified (effectively leaving out the `num_threads` parameter), and use an override value if it is. However, the default thread count seems to be implementation defined, and as far as I can tell there is no function included in OpenMP (?) that can tell me the default thread count.

Is there any means by which I can replace the ugly wasteful hack at the top of the function with some kind of environment or function call that I have overlooked?

Comment: The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61193858/openmp-best-way-to-create-an-array-with-size-of-the-number-of-threads will tell you how to figure out how many threads are available at run time, and an `if` clause on the `parallel` pragma can be used to select code paths based on a value determined at run time.